# Docker and Plumber issue with port forwarding

Tags: r, docker, plumber

Im trying to expose my plumber server over Docker. I'm getting a log from plumber in RStudio that it's listening on my desired port. And swagger launches and runs fine (the API works ok via swagger in my browser connecting over the exposed port for Rstudio of 8787).

i'm running this command as:

> docker run -e PASSWORD=rstudio --rm -it -p 8787:8787 -p 3038:3038 -v
>   "/Users/my_name/Google
>   Drive/r_files":"/home/rstudio/r-docker-tutorial" rocker/verse

if i do:

> curl http://localhost:3038

I get 'Empty reply from server'

Likewise if i attempt to hit my endpoint in Postman i get 'Could not get any response'

So it appears that the port isn't being successfully proxied by Docker, but i'm a bit stuck as this doesn't make much sense!

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Can you get a response if you run the curl command from within the container? Also, do you have an endpoint defined for the empty ("/") path?

Comment: If swagger is working fine, it means that port-mapping fro docker container is working fine too. Run `curl localhost:3038` within the container and add the output here. Would be useful to have the relevant content of the file which exposes port 3038

Comment: sorry folks, how do i connect to the container without connecting to stdout?

Comment: ive just tried following another post on here with a similar problem .. basically just bypassing starting up rstudio and im getting the same problem, here im using a dockerfile and setting EXPOSE <portnumber>, stdout shows plumber running the API on this port. The docker run command is identical to above

Answer (score 3):

Here is a template Dockerfile we use to expose plumber API :

Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.0

WORKDIR /src

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  git-core \
  libssl-dev \
  libz-dev \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
  libsodium-dev

RUN install2.r --error plumber \
  data.table \
  xgboost 

COPY ./startup.R /var
COPY ./plumber.R /var

EXPOSE 8004
ENTRYPOINT ["R", "-f", "/var/startup.R", "--slave"]
```

startup.R

```r
library(plumber)
pr <- plumb("plumber.R")
pr$run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8004)
```

plumber.R

```r
#* Health check
#* @get /
#* @serializer unboxedJSON
function() {
    list(status = "OK")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am quite new to plumber. I have solved changing what is suggested [here](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/quickstart.html) (i.e. `root %>% pr_run(port = 8004)`) into pr$run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8004). I must understand better the reason, but this single change made my day (half passed to try understanding this "bug") :-) thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to configure a plumber service in Docker; while plumber replied to the queries made within the container successfully, those queries made from the host would always result in the following error `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

I followed the code from the following example, [part 1](https://medium.com/@conalldalydev/part-1-how-to-build-a-rest-api-using-r-ad54d683f3bd) and [part 2](https://medium.com/@conalldalydev/part-2-how-to-build-a-rest-api-using-r-2405481d6821).

The clue to the solution was provided in [Bruno Tremblay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8787228/bruno-tremblay)'s answer:

```
#startup.R
library(plumber)
pr <- plumb("plumber.R")
pr$run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8004)
```

The use of `host="0.0.0.0"` is the relevant bit (plumber uses `host="127.0.0.1"` by default)